# Getting wrong output. Garbage value

Tags: c++, function, oop

Problem is, on execution, the value of `roundCost` I'm getting is
something like -1220673834. I post the entire program because I'm not
sure where I'm going wrong.

Note: I was asked to take all variables as `double` type and later,
`roundCost` should be of type `int`. So I used type conversion there.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Restaurant{ 

private:
double tip, tax,totalCost,mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent;
int roundCost;
public:

int tipCalc(double)
    {
    tip=mealCost*(tipPercent/100);
    return tip;
    }

int taxCalc(double)
    {
    tax=mealCost*(taxPercent/100);
    return tax;
    }

int totalCost1()
    {
    totalCost=mealCost+tip+tax;
    return totalCost;
    }

int roundCost1(double)
    {
    roundCost=(int)totalCost;
    return roundCost;
    }   


}; // class ends
int main()
{
double mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent, totalCost;
int roundCost;

Restaurant ob1;

cout<<"\n Enter mealCost \n";
cin>>mealCost;
cout<<"\n Enter mealtipPercent \n";
cin>>tipPercent;
cout<<"\n Enter mealtaxPercent \n";
cin>>taxPercent;
ob1.tipCalc(tipPercent);
ob1.taxCalc(taxPercent);
ob1.totalCost1();
ob1.roundCost1(totalCost);
cout<<"\n Round of cost is "<<roundCost<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) The values of variables that you read from the user are unused. 2) The member variables of the class are uninitialized. 3) `roundcost` in the `main` is uninitialized as well.

Comment: How do you set `mealCost`in your class ? You have to initialize your variables.

Comment: Try `roundCost = ob1.roundCost1(totalCost);` before the `cout`.

Comment: And what are the input and output values? Ok output is wrong, but knowing that all and the expected output will greatly help to reproduce and fix. Currently the question is just off topic for lacking necessary informations.

Comment: I like to call this SISO. For sake of stackoverflow, we'll call it "garbage in, garbage out"

Answer (score 0):

One thing you seem to be missing is that variables in your class have a different scope then variables in your main. You set the mealcost in your main from cin but you never passed this variable to the class. I changed this to be done using a constructor that sets the meal cost on creation. In every class you make you should always add a constructor. Also, you should be naming the variables your passing to functions and then using the same name in the function. For example in the tax percent function i pass double t, t is the percent, we then use t in the calculation. Your round cost variable was also private so you needed to output it via a function.

Also int functions will return a value, if you are using this type of function you should be assigning the return variable to something, but since you are just setting things in your class you can use void functions for most. The only time you use a value in the main is in the roundcost so this one is good to have it return a value. As it is int (which i assumed you wanted) it will get no decimal points and it will simply cut off any decimals in the total cost (ie 75.75 would become 75).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Restaurant{ 

private:
double tip, tax,totalCost,mealCost;
int roundCost;
public:

Restaurant (double m)
{
    mealCost = m;
}

void tipCalc(double t)
{
    tip=mealCost*(t/100.0);
}

void taxCalc(double t)
{
    tax=mealCost*(t/100.0);
}

void totalCost1()
{
    totalCost=mealCost+tip+tax;
}

int roundCost1()
{
    roundCost=(int)totalCost;
    return roundCost;
} 

}; // class ends
int main()
{
    double mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent, totalCost;
    int roundCost;


    cout<<"\n Enter mealCost \n";
    cin>>mealCost;
    Restaurant ob1(mealCost);
    cout<<"\n Enter mealtipPercent \n";
    cin>>tipPercent;
    cout<<"\n Enter mealtaxPercent \n";
    cin>>taxPercent;
    ob1.tipCalc(tipPercent);
    ob1.taxCalc(taxPercent);
    ob1.totalCost1();
    cout<<"\n Round of cost is "<<ob1.roundCost1()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Try to do a bit more research next time by using a debugger, outputting cout statements regularly and searching for the errors you find but this will give you a working code this time.

Comment: Would it had been better writing this in C, in a structural way, or as is done above in C++ ? From number of cycles standpoint, which will require less computation? C or C++ ? Especially in context of this program?

Comment: @ Scronkfinkle seriously ? you're not even trying to hide the fact that you're copying class questions here ...

Comment: @AlexGarcia Copying what? Those equations have been given to me for assignements

Comment: @Russ -  Actually I tried this code on SPOJ. It passes all test cases except one, where the inputs are 10.25 then 17 then 5. My GCC (Ubuntu 14+) gives answer as 12 dollars but the SPOJ compiler says 13 dollars. Thats the only test case where I'm failing at. Rest 3 are passed.

Comment: @Scronkfinkle Doing the calc by hand I get 12.505. As I stated in my answer, using a cast as int method to round will simply cut off the the decimal at the end giving a result of 12 when human rounding would say you should round up to 13. If you want it to round correctly you must add a decimal check inside the roundCost1() function. To do this you could use the [std::round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) function, definitions in link, or you could create your own rounding method that checks if the decimal value is greater then 0.5 and adds 1 before casting if so.